# Create a dropdownlist using ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, activerecord, drop-down-menu

I have a table called ProjectRegion. It has two columns, an id and a title. I successfully use ActiveRecord to get all the rows. I want to create a drop down list where I assign the id column to the value and the title to the text. I suspect I'll be able to do something like-

```
ProjectRegion[] projRegion = ProjectRegion.FindAll();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = ???;
DropDownList1.DataValueField = ???;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

But I don't know the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you need is:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = ProjectRegion.FindAll();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "title";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

The values for **DataTextField** and **DataValueField** are just strings referencing the properties of your ProjectRegion class.

Comment: Sorry, I think I described it incorrectly. I create the drop down menu with-
<SELECT id="DropDownList1" name="DropDownList1" runat="server"></SELECT>

Comment: I don't think those properties exist for my DropDownList1 object.
I get two build errors like:
Error 41 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayMember' and no extension method 'DisplayMember' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)